# [C]unrecognized token "@address" on VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, stm8

I'm using cosmic compiler for stm8 microcontroller.
It supports "@" pointers or modifiers.
such like

```
@<address>
@far
@near
@tiny
@interrupt
@inline
//etc..
```

[Cosmic compiler user guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSfUt.png)

VScode cannot recognize those modifiers and shows red underline and also intellisense does not work.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHWVm.png)

Does VScode have any setting to enable "@" pointers or modifiers?
Or can it ignore "@" symbols? I just wanna use intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

I used defines for these and defined those as nothing when the VS_CODE define is defined whitch i did in the c_cpp_properties.json. than vs code sees nothing and cosmic is happy to see the @ where they are needed

```
#ifdef VS_CODE
    #define TINY
    #define NEAR
    #define FAR
    #define EEPROM
    #define AT_ADR(n)
    #define INLINE
    #define _INLINE
    #define INTERRUPT
#else
    #define FAR  @far
    #define NEAR @near
    #define TINY @tiny
    #define __CONST  const
    #define EEPROM @eeprom
    #define AT_ADR(n) @(n)
    #define INLINE @inline
    #define INTERRUPT @interrupt
#endif
```